# Recursive glob?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, recursive

I'd like to write something like this:

```
$ ls **.py
```

in order to get all .py filenames, recursively walking a directory hierarchy.

Even if there are .py files to find, the shell (bash) gives this output:

```
ls: cannot access **.py: No such file or directory
```

Any way to do what I want?

**EDIT:** I'd like to specify that I'm not interested in the specific case of `ls`, but the question is about the glob syntax.

Comment: Related: [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62660)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

In order to do recursive globs in bash, you need the `globstar` feature from Bash version 4 or higher.

From the [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> `globstar`
>        If set, the pattern `**` used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

For your example pattern:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -d -- **/*.py
```

**You must run `shopt -s globstar` in order for this to work.** This feature is not enabled by default in bash, by running `shopt` you are activating the feature.

Comment: I'd recommend also enabling `nullglob`

Comment: @glennjackman But before enabling `nullglob`, I would strongly advise reading following [warnings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob).

Comment: ^ Warnings have moved [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Warning).

Comment: With bash 3.2, `wc -l {**,.}/*.py` works just fine

Comment: @Raphael I double checked the release notes and it definitely says that it was introduced in 4.0. Perhaps you distribution has backported a patch for it? IIRC RHEL 5 had backported some features. Also of note, it's been 9 years since bash 4 was released...

Comment: Um, I guess that's possible? I was working on macOS 10.13, who knows what they ship why...

Comment: Wayback Machine link, for the link above: https://web.archive.org/web/http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: Too bad the GNU C library `glob` function has no `GLOB_STAR` equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -name '*.py'
```

** doesn't do anything more than a single *, both operate in the current directory

Comment: Interesting. Though, I'm more focused on the glob syntax by itself, because I have to use it in a configuration file (include directive). I don't need a list of files.

Comment: @Doug O'Neal, that's no longer true. bash has now copied that zsh feature (though it adopted a syntax closer to that of ksh93 and like ksh, doesn't support zsh's globbing qualifiers yet which limits its usefulness)

Comment: There are lots of things you can do with `find` if you don't have bash 4.  Examples: `yourcommand \`find . -name '*.py'\`` (note the backticks); `find . -name '*.py' -exec yourcommand {} \;`.

Answer (score 20):

Since Bash 4 (also including zsh) [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`globstar`) has been added which treats the pattern `**` differently when it's set.

It is matching the wildcard pattern and returning the file and directory names that match then by replacing the wildcard pattern in the command with the matched items.

Normally when you use `**`, it works similar to `*`, but it's recurses all the directories recursively (like a loop).

To see if it's enabled, check it by `shopt globstar` (in scripting, use `shopt -q globstar`).

The example `**.py` would work only for the current directory, as it doesn't return list of directories which can be recurses, so that's why you need to use multiple directory-level wildcard `**/*.py`, so it can go deeper.

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731174/55075) for examples of finding files recursively.

Comment: Thanks! The globstar can be enabled by ``shopt -s globstar``.