# The result of ls * , ls ** and ls ***

Tags: directory, ls, wildcards

I know using the command `ls` will list all the directories. But what does the `ls *` command do ? I used it and it just lists the directories. Does the star in front of `ls` mean how deep it will list the directories?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

`ls` lists the files and content of directories it is being passed as arguments, and if no argument is given, it lists the current directory. It can also be passed a number of options that affect its behaviour (see `man ls` for details).

If `ls` is being passed an argument called `*`, it will look for a file or directory called `*` in the current directory and list it just like any other. `ls` doesn't treat the `*` character in any other way than any other one.

However if `ls *` is a **shell** command line, that is *code in the language of a Unix shell*, then the shell will expand that `*` according to its *globbing* (also referred to as *Filename Generation* or *Filename/Pathname Expansion*) rules.

While different shells support different globbing  operators, most of them agree on the simplest one `*`. `*` as a pattern means any number of characters, so `*` as a `glob` will expand to the list of files in the current directories that match that pattern. There's an exception however that a leading dot (`.`) character in a file name has to be matched explicitly, so `*` actually expands to the list of files and directories not starting with `.` (in lexical order).

For instance, if the current directory contains the files called `.`, `..`, `.foo`, `-l` and `foo bar`, `*` will be expanded by the shell to two arguments to pass to `ls`: `-l` and `foo bar`, so it will be as if you had typed:

```bash
ls -l "foo bar"
```

or

```bash
'ls' "-l" foo\ bar
```

Which are three ways to run exactly the same command. In all 3 cases, the `ls` command (which will probably be executed from `/bin/ls` from a lookup of directories mentioned in `$PATH`) will be passed those 3 arguments: "ls", "-l" and "foo bar".

Incidentally, in this case, `ls` will treat the first (strictly speaking *second*) one as an option.

Now, as I said, different shells have different globbing operators. A few decades ago, `zsh` introduced the `**/` operator¹ which means to match any level of subdirectories, short for `(*/)#` and `***/` which is the same except that it follows symlinks while descending the directories.

A few years ago (July 2003, `ksh93o+`), `ksh93` decided to copy that behaviour but decided to make it optional, and only covered the `**` case (not `***`). Also, while `**` alone was not special in `zsh`² (just meant the same as `*` like in other traditional shells since `**` means any number of character followed by any number of characters), in ksh93, `**` meant the same as `**/*` (so any file or directory below the current one (excluding hidden files)³.

`bash` copied `ksh93` a few years later (February 2009, bash 4.0), with the same syntax but an unfortunate difference: bash's `**` was like `zsh`'s `***`, that is it was following symlinks when recursing into sub-directories which is generally not what you want it do and can have nasty side effects. It was partly fixed in bash-4.3 in that symlinks were still followed, but recursion stopped there. It was fully fixed in 5.0.

`yash` added `**` in version 2.0 in 2008, enabled with the `extended-glob` option. Its implementation is closer to `zsh`'s in that `**` alone is not special. In version 2.15 (2009), it added `***` like in `zsh` and two of its own extensions: `.**` and `.***` to include hidden dirs when recursing (in `zsh`, the `D` *glob qualifier* (as in `**/*(D)`) will consider hidden files and directories, but if you only want to traverse hidden dirs but not expand hidden files, you need `((*|.*)/)#*` or `**/[^.]*(D)`).

[fish](http://fishshell.com) also supports `**`. Like earlier version of `bash`, it follows symlinks when descending the directory tree. In that shell however `**/*` is not the same as `**`. `**` is more an extension of `*` that can span several directories. In `fish`, `**/*.c` will match `a/b/c.c` but not `a.c`, while `a**.c` will match `a.c` and `ab/c/d.c` and `zsh`'s `**/.*` for instance has to be written `{,**/}.*`. There, `***` is understood as `**` followed by `*` so the same as `**`.

`tcsh` also added a `globstar` option in V6.17.01 (May 2010) and supports both `**` and `***` à la `zsh`.

So in `tcsh`, `bash` and `ksh93`, (when the corresponding option is enabled (`globstar`)) or `fish`, `**` expands all the files and directories below the current one, and `***` is the same as `**` for `fish`, a symlink traversing `**` for `tcsh` with `globstar`, and the same as `*` in `bash` and `ksh93` (though it's not impossible that future versions of those shells will also traverse symlinks).

Above, you'll have noticed the need to make sure none of the expansions is interpreted as an options. For that, you'd do:

```bash
ls -- *
```

Or:

```bash
ls ./*
```

There are some commands (it doesn't matter for `ls`) where the second is preferable since even with the `--` some filenames may be treated specially. It's the case of `-` for most text utilities, `cd` and `pushd` and filenames that contain the `=` character for `awk` for instance. Prepending `./` to all the arguments removes their special meaning (at least for the cases mentioned above).

It should also be noted that most shells have a number of options that affect the globbing behaviour (like whether dot files are ignored or not, the sorting order, what to do if there's no match...), see also the `$FIGNORE` parameter in `ksh`

Also, in every shell but `csh`, `tcsh`, `fish` and `zsh`, if the *globbing pattern* doesn't match any file, the pattern is passed as an unexpanded argument which causes confusion and possibly bugs. For instance, if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory

```bash
ls *
```

Will actually call `ls` with the two arguments `ls` and `*`. And as there's no file at all, so none called `*` either, you'll see an error message from **ls** (not the shell) like: `ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory`, which has been known to make people think that it was `ls` that was actually expanding the globs.

The problem is even worse in cases like:

```bash
rm -- *.[ab]
```

If there's no `*.a` nor `*.b` file in the current directory, then you might end up deleting a file called `*.[ab]` by mistake (`csh`, `tcsh`, and `zsh` would report a *no match* error and wouldn't call `rm` (and `fish` doesn't support the `[...]` wildcards)).

If you do want to pass a literal `*` to `ls`, you have to quote that `*` character in some way as in `ls \*` or `ls '*'` or `ls "*"`. In POSIX-like shells, globbing can be disabled altogether using `set -o noglob` or `set -f` (the latter not working in `zsh` unless in `sh`/`ksh` emulation).

---

<sup>¹ While `(*/)#` was always supported, it was first short-handed as `..../` in zsh-2.0 (and potentially before), then `****/` in 2.1 before getting its definitive form `**/` in 2.2 (early 1992)</sup>

<sup>² The [`globstarshort` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOBSTARSHORT), has since be added (in 2015) to allow `**` and `***` being used instead of `**/*` and `***/*` respectively</sup>

<sup>³ See also [these few more oddities with the ksh93 `globstar` design](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/146), some of which were copied by `bash`.</sup>.

Comment: Another nice example is `find -name *`. Especially with more complex patterns, if there is exactly one match in the current directory, people will often not realize they're not passing the asterisk to `find`.

Comment: In fish, `*.[ab]` would try to delete everything ending with `.[ab]`. `[` is not special in fish.

Answer (score 39):

The command `ls` defaults to `ls .`: *List all entries in the current directory*.

The command `ls *` means 'run ls on the expansion of the `*` shell pattern'

The `*` pattern is processed by the shell, and expands to all entries in the current directory, except those that start with a `.`.  It will go one level deep.

The interpretation of double or triple `*` patterns depend on the actual shell used.

`*` is a wildcard that matches 0 or more characters.  Some modern shells will recurse into subdirectories on seeing the `**` pattern.

Comment: Except that extra `*` *do* add something, see the other answer explaining the globstar. It should also be made clear that ls has *nothing* to do with the asterisks, it's never passed any of these asterisks at all. Run `echo ls *` to see what would be executed when you write `ls *`.

Answer (score 16):

You can demystify the whole process by typing `echo` instead of `ls` first, to see what the command expands to:

```
$ echo *
Applications Downloads Documents tmp.html
```

So in this case, `ls *` expands to `ls Applications Downloads Documents tmp.html`

```
$ echo **
Applications Downloads Documents tmp.html

$ echo ***
Applications Downloads Documents tmp.html
```

So no change. This assumes you're using `bash` as your shell -- most people are, and different shells have different behavior. If you're using `ash` or `csh` or `ksh` or `zsh`, you may expect things to work differently. That's the point of having different shells.

So lets try something different (still with `bash`) so we get an idea of the the globbing (`*`) operator can do for us. For example, we can filter by part of the name:

```
$ echo D*
Downloads Documents
```

And interestingly, a trailing slash is an implicitly part of any directory name. So `*/` will yield only the directories (and symbolic links to directories):

```
$ echo */
Applications/ Downloads/ Documents/
```

And we can do some filtering at multiple levels by putting slashes in the middle:

```
$ echo D*/*/
Documents/Work/ /Documents/unfinished/
```

Since the `Downloads` directory doesn't contain any subdirectories, it does not end up in the output. This is very useful for just examining the files you want. I use commands like this all the time:

```
$ ls -l /home/*/public_html/wp-config.php
```

This lists, if there are any, all the `wp-config.php` files that exist at the base level of any user's `public_html` directory. Or perhaps to be more complete:

```
$ find /home/*/public_html/ -name wp-config.php
```

This will find any `wp-config.php` files in any user's `public_html` directories or any of their subdirectories, but it will operate more efficiently than just `find /home/ -name wp-config.php` because it won't examine anything *but* the `public_html` directories for each of the users.

Comment: "This assumes you're using `bash` as your shell" ← and that the globstar is not enabled. `shopt -s globstar` and try it again...

Comment: Another way to demystify is `set -x` which will start printing the "actual" command executed each time (turn off with `set +x`).

Answer (score 10):

In some shells, including bash 4.x with the `globstar` option enabled, `**` will perform a recursive glob, descending matched directories. Additional asterisks don't further modify this operation.

Comment: As I said in my answer though, beware that contrary to `ksh93` and `zsh`, `bash` does traverse symlinks in the recursion which is generally unwanted.

Comment: That has now been fixed in bash 4.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "dive deep", use ls -R (recursive) option, or use find, like so:

```
find . -ls
```

"find" will dive down to the bottom of the directory tree (as will 'ls -R'), and has many more options, like listing directories (-type d), files only (-type f) or showing files having other characteristics (no user in /etc/passwd, specific permissions, and a whole lot more).  "find" is also somewhat safer in scripting (due to inconsistent globbing rules between shells, as well as special escapes for files having dashes, etc).

shell wildcard globbing won't work with just an asterisk '*' on dotfiles.  To list dotfiles only, use:

`ls .??*`

Comment: I never understood why if `ls -R` gives results containing foo.xml, `ls -R *.xml` doesn't. At least that's true for macos's ls. Any clues?

Comment: @SteakOverflow If the `foo.xml` is not in the directory it won't find it because it's not in the directory but a subdirectory. That's why. `ls -R` recurses into subdirectories so it shows the files found but when running `ls -R *.xml` it's trying to recurse through directories in the current directory - but it doesn't exist in the current directory but rather a subdirectory so it can't search it. I hope that's clear. I'm exhausted.