# How to move all files with a certain file extension from subdirectories to a single directory

Tags: shell, files, rename

I have a directory that contains many subdirectories. The subdirectories contain lots of types of files with different file extensions. I want to move (not copy)  all the files of one type into a new directory. I need all these files to be in the same directory, i.e. it needs to be flat.

(My use case is that I want to move ebooks called *.epub from many directories into a single folder that an EPUB reader can find.)

Comment: For that use case: Maybe it's better not to move the files but to link them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In zsh, you can use a recursive glob:

```
mkdir ~/epubs
mv -- **/*.epub ~/epubs/
```

In bash ≥4, run `shopt -s globstar` (you can put this in your `~/.bashrc`) then the command above. In ksh, run `set -o globstar` first.

With only POSIX tools, run `find`:

```
find . -name '*.epub' -exec mv {} ~/epubs \;
```

Comment: Note that `bash` (and `fish`) contrary to zsh or ksh93 do follow symlinks when descending the directory tree (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/22565) for details). `find` will include dot files and follow dotdirs, not `**`. With `**`, you may run into the _too many args_ limit which `zsh` and `ksh93` have work around for, but not `bash`.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this :

```
mkdir ../new_dir
find . -type f -name '*.epub' -exec mv {} ../new_dir/ \;
```

if all the files are named `name.epub`, then you need to increment a variable like this (using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) )

```
mkdir ../new_dir
find . -type f -name '*.epub' |
    while read a; do
        ((c++))
        base="${a##*/}"
        mv "$a" "../new_dir/${base%.epub}_$(printf %.03d $c).epub"
    done
```

Comment: That's going to end up with a lot of error messages if the target directory is part of the search tree... Thus if you want to create it there above all then use `-prune` at least.

Comment: post edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Using bash under Linux:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
mv -t ~/epub_directory ~/big_dir/**/*.epub
```

Comment: Note that there's nothing Linux-specific in there. `mv -t` is _GNU_ specific though (and most Linux distributions have GNU `mv` as their `mv`). There's no reason to be using `mv -t` here though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I added that. In practice, for most people, GNU <-> Linux || Cygwin (as opposed to OSX, *BSD, Solaris). I didn't see the point of using `mv -t` either but didn't feel comfortable changing that (it's a matter of style rather than correctness).

Comment: I originally had something a bit more complicated piping in to `xargs mv -t dir`. I left that form of mv here