# I quite like mercurial .hgignore-style globbing. Is there a Linux shell that supports it?

Tags: shell, wildcards, recursive, mercurial, glob

I quite like [mercurial .hgignore-style pattern globbing](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns).

> Globs are rooted at the current directory; a glob such as *.c will only match files in the current directory ending with .c.
>
> The supported glob syntax extensions are ** to match any string across path separators and {a,b} to mean "a or b".

Is there a Linux shell that supports this?

Comment: The section you quote is actually not about the `.hgignore` ignore patterns — they're *not* rooted for example. The section is about the general pattern supported by all commands. You use them like `hg add "set:**.c"`, which works even when your shell doesn't (e.g., on Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All shells will support the standard glob `*.c`. KSH, Bash, and ZSH support brace expansion (`{a,b}`), but note that this not a file glob, so it will always expand. ZSH's extended globbing and Bash's `globstar` (bash v4 or higher), support `**` for recursive globbing.

Comment: brace expansion originates in `csh`, `**` comes from `zsh` (1991) and is now supported by `ksh93` and `tcsh`. Also with `bash` and `fish` but with the caveat that they follow symlinks when recursing. `zsh` and `tcsh` have `***` to follow symlinks.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I tested `**` in `ksh93` without the expected results. Does it require enabling a feature like `globstar` in `bash`?

Comment: yes, they all do except `zsh`. `set -G` in ksh93. `bash` got it from `ksh93` as most things. See also [that answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/22565)

Comment: @jordanm Thank you for suggesting Bash `globstar`. It is especially the recursive `**` that I am after.

Comment: In Bash you can use `shopt -s nullglob` as well to avoid getting literally `*.c` if there is no file match.