# What is the meaning of the string **/* when used with grep?

Tags: shell, command-line, wildcards

I came across this picture (below), obviously it is a pun or some kind of allusion incorporating command-line expressions. Frankly speaking I do not understand anything of it except for `grep -n`. However, I searched for the string "**/*" via google and I did not even get one hit.

[image: image with **/* example command]

Comment: That's [`zsh` recursive globbing now supported by a few other shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/22565)

Comment: This should be closed as off-topic because *asp* is Microsoft file extension.

Comment: @jimmij you can serve asp on Linux via `mod_mono`.

Comment: @jimmij besides, you can run grep via cygwin.

Comment: so, if "**/*" is recursive does it display all paths that exist in the filesystem? I ask, because I tried two commands: 1) find / | wc -l 2) ls **/* | wc -l .....the first command had more than ten times as many lines

Answer (score 2):

To round out the comments into an Answer,

- [`grep -n`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) will search for the given expression in the given files or standard input, reporting the line number that matches were found on.
- `\"in$Ps\"` is the expression that grep is looking for. Since the double-quotes are quoted, they are part of the text that grep will search for. The `$Ps` part is a little unclear to me, since the shell will try to interpret `Ps` as a variable name.

  If `$Ps` is not set, then `grep` will search for the text: `"in"`.

  If `$Ps` **is** set, then the shell will replace that part of the expression with the value of `$Ps`; for example, if `Ps=42`, then `grep`'s expression will be: `"in42"`.

  If `$Ps` is a value that contains whitespace, this will be split into words (as the expansion is unquoted) and it would break the command.  The resulting string would also undergo filename globbing if any wildcard characters (such as `*`) is present in `$Ps`.

  My best guess is that it's a reference to using PowerShell in VBScript.
- As [Stéphane said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186690/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-string-when-used-with-grep#comment311364_186690), the `**` is an extended globbing syntax, which here is used twice, in order to pull up all of the files ending in `.asp` and `.js` from within the current directory as well as from subdirectories (recursively) as ones for `grep` to search through.  It is used by the shell, not by `grep`.

Long story short, the code will display file names and corresponding line numbers for lines that match `\"in\"`, where `in` is followed by whatever value `$Ps` holds.