# How to use the ls command to list all files that start with 'r'

Tags: linux, bash

I need to use the ls command to list files that begin with the letter 'r'.

Comment: Watch out that is a **trick question**. `ls` cannot be used to look in the contents of the file to see if it starts with the letter `r` you would need  `head` and `grep`  for that or alternatively `awk`, `ls` only works with filenames.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls r*
```

Explanation: The `*` is a special character that does Filename Expansion when run in a shell, essentially expanding out the `r` character to anything in that directory that starts with an `r`.  See this for a full explanation. [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

For questions on command lines commands, type

```
man <command>
```

To see the manual pages for that command, so

```
man ls
```

Comment: This didn't work, I am trying to list files of the bin directory so I did `ls /bin r*` and it told me that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Try `ls /bin/r*`
This will still list the /bin part, so if you just want the bin names you can do
`ls /bin | grep -e ^r`
the `^` character indicates beginning of line.

Comment: Joseph, RegEx are completely irrelevant here

Comment: Oh, I see, it has to do with globbing.  Logan, see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls) for a better explanation of what is going on.
`grep -e [PATTERN]` does use regex though, so if you pipe to grep you can do more complex patterns like that.

Comment: Try: `echo $(cd /bin; ls r*)`. No grep needed.