# What's the equivalent wildcard operator in Zsh to Bash's *

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have just started using Zsh and I have noticed that the asterisk (`*`) wildcard operator does not seem to work in it. For example, running `cd ~/Doc*` does not change me into the `~/Documents` directory when I run it as standard (non-superuser) user. What's Zsh's equivalent to Bash's `*` wildcard operator?

Comment: See also: [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62660)

Comment: Nitpicking: a wildcard in globbing is actually one of `?`, `*`, or `[` - not just an asterisk. Of course with the shell it's not a regex but a glob but some might call that a thinner line (though there are important differences of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `*`.

```
% pwd
/homes/jdoe
% ls D*
zsh: no matches found: D*
% mkdir Documents
% cd Doc*
% pwd
/homes/jdoe/Documents
%
```

If the above Does Not Work(TM) for you, try it under `zsh -f`, which will disable any screwball code (e.g. oh-my-zsh) that might be throwing a monkey wrench into your shell configuration.