# Flatten the output of a recursive directory listing

Tags: files, ls, recursive

Is there a way to list out all the files within a directory *tree* in a single list, sorted by modification time on Linux?

```
ls -Rlt
```

lists out files recursively, but they are grouped under different folders in the output and as a result, the output isn't sorted as a whole. Only the contents of each directory are sorted by time.

Comment: Do you also want to list directories or only files?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can do this with GNU `find`. If your file names don't contain newlines, you can do:

```
find -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -gk1,1
```

#### Explanation

- The `-printf` option of `find` can print all sorts of information. In this case, we are using:

  ```
  %Tk    File's last modification time in the format specified  by
         k, which is the same as for %A.
  @      seconds  since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part.
  %p     File's name.
  ```

  So, `%T@ %p\n` will print the file's modification time in seconds since the epoch (`%T@`), a space, and then the file's name (`%p`).
- These are then passed to `sort` which is told to sort numerically (`-n`) on the first field only (`-k1,1`).

Note that this will return all files and directories. To restrict it to regular files only (no directories, device files, links etc.) add `-type f` to your `find` command.

To get human readable dates, you can process the output with GNU `date`:

```
find -printf '%T@ %p\t\n' | sort -gk1,1 | 
    perl -lne 's/([^ ]*)//;chomp($i=`date -d \@$1`); print "$i $_"'
```

Here, the `perl` command replaces the first string of non-space characters (the date) with itself as processed by GNU `date`.

---

The above will fail for file names that contain newlines. To deal with newlines, use:

```
find -printf '%p\t%T@\0' | sort -zt$'\t' -nk2 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

That's the same thing except that `find` will output a `\0` instead of `\n` at the end of each file name. GNU `sort` can deal with null-separated output so it is still able to sort correctly. The final `tr` command translates the `\0` back to `\n`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing as well (with the time first).  It also needs GNU findutils.

Comment: @chexum ah yes, thanks. I keep forgetting that `-printf` isn't POSIX.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can I modify this command to print the modify times in  human readable format?

Comment: @mahela007 yes. You'd need to use `date` to reformat it: `find -printf '%T@ %p\t\n' | sort -gk1,1 | sed -E "s/([^ ]*)/$(date -d \1)/"`. See updated answer. I also fixed the (completely unnecessary) use of tabs.

Comment: @mikeserv indeed I wasn't, thanks. It should work now.

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- **/*(D.om)
```

[**/*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/38906) match any level of subdirectories (and not follow symlinks). `D.` qualifiers list regular files, `om` sort them by modification time, newest first.

If you want the file names to be listed without the directory part, add the `t` history modifier:

```
print -rl -- **/*(D.om:t)
```

Comment: what is zsh? ()

Comment: @mahela007: It's another unix shell, with many advance features added http://www.zsh.org/

Answer (score 2):

well, if you're talking about many many thousands of files - and so beyond your `ARG_MAX` limit - then it won't come out so well, but the most simple solution is:

```
find . ! -type d -exec ls -t {} +
```

...which will call `ls` for every batch of `<=ARG_MAX` files which it can find. There are no arbitrary restrictions on the characters in the pathnames, either, just on the maximum number of arguments which might be processed together.

It will write output identically to `find`'s output. You can use any other option, of course, such as `-l` or GNU's `-h`. Here are a few it listed from a small tree I created a week ago:

```
find . ! -type d -exec ls -lht {} +
```

---

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir/dir1/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir/dir2/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir/dir3/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir2/dir1/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir2/dir2/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 19:00 ./dir2/dir3/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir/file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir/file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir/file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir2/file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir2/file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv   0 Dec 19 18:57 ./dir2/file3
```

...which are quite obviously not grouped by directory.

On my machine...

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

---

```
2091752
```

...but I don't think that's realistic. I think it's something more like 65k or so on average.