# use printf to format output of an array

Tags: shell-script, array, printf

I have an array that contains details about each NIC. 
Each array index consists of three space-separated values.

I would like to have a nice table as output. Is there a way to assign formatting patterns to each value in an index?

so far this is what I use:

```
NIC_details[0]='wlp2s0 192.168.1.221 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
NIC_details[1]='wwan0 none xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
NIC_details[2]='virbr0 192.168.122.1 00:00:00:00:00:00'

printf "%-20s\n" "${NIC_details[@]}"
```

Is there a way to access the values in an array index by their position $1, $2, and $3, knowing that they are space-separated, and then apply a formatting pattern for each $X position?

I have also tried

```
echo "$i" | column -t
```

but it does not bring the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slight modification to what you were already doing:

```
set -f # to prevent filename expansion
for i in ${!NIC_index[@]}
do
  printf "%-20s" ${NIC_details[i]}
  printf "\n"
done
```

I added a `for` loop to go over all of the array indexes -- that's the `${!NIC...` syntax. Since it's a numeric array, you could alternatively loop directly over the indexes.

Note that I intentionally left `${NIC_details[i]}` *unquoted* so that the shell would split the value on the spaces that you've used to separate the values. `printf` thus sees the 3 values and so repeats the %-20s formatting for each of them. I then add a newline after each NIC to make a nice table.

The `set -f` at the top is important if we leave variables unquoted; otherwise the shell will step in and attempt to [glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/117549) any wildcards it sees in unquoted variables.

Sample output:

```
wlp2s0              192.168.1.221       xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wwan0               none                xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
virbr0              192.168.122.1       00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way, use `awk`.
One example :

```
echo ${NIC[0]} | awk '{ printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $2 }'
```

Another way would be to get the values in different variables and then do the `printf` from bash.
Like :

```
var1=$(echo ${NIC[0]} | cut -d ' ' -f1)
var2=$(echo ${NIC[0]} | cut -d ' ' -f2)
var3=$(echo ${NIC[0]} | cut -d ' ' -f3)
```

And use the `printf` with $var1,2,3 .