# Can someone explain the meaning of -- and ** in a linux/unix command?

Tags: grep, zsh, wildcards, disk-usage

```
du -ch -- **/*.jpg | grep total
```

Especially, what do the `--` (double dash) and `**` (double asterisk) really mean?

Using the Z shell

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls/62665#62665

Comment: The meaning of `**/*.jpg` depends on the shell you are using. Please [edit you question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/457398/edit) and tell us which shell are you using.

Comment: @andcoz Z Shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `**` in `zsh` matches just like `*`, but allows for matching across `/` in pathnames. The pattern `**/*.jpg` will therefore expand to the pathname of any file that has a filename suffix of `.jpg` anywhere in or below the current directory.

The `**` pattern is available in `bash` as well, if enabled with `shopt -s globstar`.  The `ksh93` shell has it too, if enabled with `set -o globstar`.

The `--` prevents any pathname (matching the above pattern) that starts with a dash from being interpreted by `du` as a command line option.  The `--` stops the command line parsing of `du` from looking for further options.  This is not dependent on the shell but is a POSIX "[utility guideline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)" for standard utilities.

The `--` could be removed if the filename globbing pattern was changed to `./**/*.jpg`.

The command would give you the total size of all `*.jpg` files in or below the current directory by extracting the line with the total from the output of `du` (run the command without `| grep total` to see what `du` produces).

Comment: Note that `**` alone is not special in `zsh`.  `**/` is and is short for extended_glob `(*/)#`. `tcsh`, `yash` and `fish` now also have one form or the other of `**`. Your description matches more closely the `fish` implementation. See [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665) for more details

Answer (score 0):

From man-page of du
usage

```
du [OPTION][PARAM]

du - lists disk space used by files

c - displays total 
h - human readable format (24M= meaning 24 MB)
```

`--` - usually means end of option parameters
 `**/*.jpg`- glob to go find all paths matching this path (foo/bar.jpg)
 `|` -pipe

```
 grep total- this option is not required and is redundant, since -c[OPTION] is giving you grand total anyways.
```

TL;DR: This lists the total disk size of pictures in .jpg format from one step inside directory from current directory.

Eg- If your current Directory is `~/Pictures` then running this command will list file size of all .jpg files inside recursively.(~/Pictures/EuropeTrip/pic134.jpg) [*] means all for regex.

Not sure what (grep total) is doing/ or adding to the output, and maybe unnecessary here.

Comment: `**/*.jpg` is not a regex, it is a glob.

Comment: yes a glob , removed by apppending . at start, easier to visualise as regex

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the phrase “removed by apppending . at start, easier to visualise as regex”.

Comment: You are correct @ctrl-alt-delor, It is a glob, although filename glob and regex are completely different altogether, the output is same - All jpg files  under current directory.See Kusalananda's answer mentioning about this.

Comment: While the output may be the same, as that produced by a regular expression, that produces the same output. The regular expression is different. `.*/.*\.jpg` (regex) vs `**/*.jpg` (glob).