# globstar: `**string*` not descending into subdirs `**/*string*` does

Tags: bash, shopt

Given is a set of files in (sub)directories matching a string like in e.g.:

```
find -name 'string' | sort
./1/2/3/4/string
./1/2/3/string
./1/2/string
./1/string
./string
```

Why does using `globstar` to match the files like in

```
ls **string
string
```

fail to run through the directories, while

```
ls **/string
1/2/3/4/string  1/2/3/string  1/2/string  1/string  string
```

succeeds? From my understanding of the description in the `man` pages it should be matching (sub)directories, shuldn't it?

Question like this usually are marked as duplicate of ["The result of ls * , ls ** and ls ***"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls), yet the answer there only handles `ls **`, which indeed does recurse through directories. It seems as if a double asterisk followed by a string would break `globstar`.

Running `GNU bash v.4.4.19(1)` on `mint 19`

---

From `man bash`

> **globstar**
>
> If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation could use some clarification; the code ([`glob_filename` in lib/glob/glob.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/glob/glob.c#n1011)) specifically checks for `**/` (and not `**`) in several places. ( Search for `filename[1] == '*'` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way it works in Ksh and Zsh too.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/cdir
$ touch    a/b/cfile
$ ksh -c 'set -o globstar; echo **c*'
**c*
$ zsh -c 'echo **c*'
zsh:1: no matches found: **c*
```

Under Pattern Matching, Bash's manual says:

> When the `globstar` shell option is enabled, and `*` is used in a filename expansion context, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.

I suppose that could be read as meaning that "a single pattern" is a part separated by slashes, so `foo/**/bar` has it in a single pattern, but `**bar` doesn't.

It could be clearer, though.

A trailing slash after the whole pattern makes the pattern match just directories:

```
$ echo **/c*/
a/b/cdir/
```

Comment: Indeed in combination with @jeff-schaller 's comment on the source code, it seems like this is intended behaviour and that the documentation is a bit unclear in this point.

Answer (score 2):

A double `*` decays to the effect of one `*` when it is not limited by (only) `/`:

```
$ ls *c
abc  ac  acc  bc  cc  dc

$ ls **c
abc  ac  acc  bc  cc  dc
```

Any character leading or trailing that is not a `/` makes the `**` decay:

That is simply because a path name (as a file name) can **not** contain any `/`.
It is not possible for a `*` to expand to a name containing `/`. A `**` is somewhat similar, it will expand to strings containing `/` **only** when alone or delimited by `/` (not any other character/string):

```
$ ls -d ./** | sort
./
./1
./1/2
./1/2/3
./1/2/3/4
./1/2/3/4/string
./1/2/3/string
./1/2/string
./1/string
./abc
./ac
./acc
./bc
./cc
./dc
./string

$ ls -d ./**c | sort 
./abc
./ac
./acc
./bc
./cc
./dc

$ ls -d ** | sort
1
1/2
1/2/3
1/2/3/4
1/2/3/4/string
1/2/3/string
1/2/string
1/string
abc
ac
acc
bc
cc
dc
string

$ ls -d **c | sort
abc
ac
acc
bc
cc
dc

$ ls -d **/ | sort
1/
1/2/
1/2/3/
1/2/3/4/

$ ls -d 1**/ | sort
1/
```