# Why is the triple question mark globbing (???) not working with ls?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

I am trying to list all files with a name of 3 characters in `/usr/bin`.

`ls ???` should do exactly that, but it lists every file in the directory.
Note that `ls ????` works as intended, showing only the files with a name of 4 characters. It also works with 1, 2, 5 and literally every number other than 3.

Steps to reproduce:

- go to `/usr/bin`
- type `ls ???`

Comment: This must be an interesting artifact of a filename in there, because that doesn't seem to happen for any other folder.

Comment: `ls -d ???` works as intended.

Comment: which version of `ls` are you running? `type ls` and `ls --version`? The GNU one on the one box I tried doesn't follow the symlink with that command, and e.g. `ls -l X11` shows the link, while `ls -l X11/` shows the contents of the dir behind the link. (which is different for a regular directory) `ls -H` would change that, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I tested with **ls (GNU coreutils) 8.28** and it is subject to this behaviour. Please notice that `ls -l ???` works OK for me.

Comment: Scroll up! You'll see a listing of the three-letter files, then a blank line, a line with `X11:` and then all the file names.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I found it: ls will list the contents of directories you pass it on the command line. At least on the Ubuntu I tried this on, there is `/usr/bin/X11/` which is a symlink to  `/usr/bin/`. So you do get the three-letter files first, and then you get all the contents of `/usr/bin` again, which scrolls out all the others. (Try `ls ??? | less` to see this.)

Comment: Consider using `-d` with `ls` when you give an explicit list of items to list to `ls`.  If you just want the list, you may just as well use `echo ???` or `printf '%s\n' ???`.