# cp some/path/**/*.h is not including .h files at all depths

Tags: bash, wildcards, cp

I'm trying to copy all .h files in a directory and all subdirectories into another folder using the copy command:

```
cp --parents -r tensorflow/lite/**/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
```

The above glob only copies .h files in `tensorflow/lite/XXX/*.h` and doesn't include .h files further down (eg. `tensorflow/lite/XXX/XXX.h`) or in the root (`tensorflow/lite/*.h`). To workaround this, I have to issue several `cp` commands for all expected levels of recursion:

```
cp --parents -r tensorflow/lite/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
cp --parents -r tensorflow/lite/**/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
cp --parents -r tensorflow/lite/**/**/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
cp --parents -r tensorflow/lite/**/**/**/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
```

I know I'm missing something obvious here. Is there an easier way to create a glob that says "all files ending in .h in all subdirectories recursively"?

Comment: Do you have the `globstar` option set in your shell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`**/` to match any level of subdirectories is from the zsh shell from 1992.

ksh93 did copy it in 2003, but made it disabled by default for backward compatibility (where before `**` was the same as `*`), enabled with `set -G`/`set -o globstar`. `bash` was one of the last shells to add that feature in 2009 but did it à la ksh93 (though bogus until 5.0), enabled with `shopt -s globstar`.

So:

```
cp --parents tensorflow/lite/**/*.h libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include
```

Would work in zsh (or to some extent `fish` where `**` is enabled by default though works slightly differently from zsh), but you'd need to enable the `globstar` or equivalent option in other shells first:

```
set   -o globstar      # ksh93
set   -o extended-glob # yash
set      globstar      # tcsh
shopt -s globstar      # bash
```

For more details, see: [The result of ls * , ls ** and ls ***](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62660)

Comment: Ah this explained why the same command worked on my Mac but not on linux. Thanks

Comment: @Brad: This also explained why no other shell should be used. :D

Answer (score 6):

This command will find all `.h` files in `tensorflow/lite` and its subdirectories and copy them with their relative paths to the destination directory `libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include`.

```
find tensorflow/lite -type f -name "*.h" -exec cp --parents {} libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include/ \;
```

`find tensorflow/lite`

- Starts the search from the `tensorflow/lite` directory.

`-type f`

- Tells find to only look for files, not directories.

`-name "*.h"`

- Specifies that only files with the .h extension should be considered.

`-exec cp --parents {} libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include \;`

- `-exec` runs `cp` on each found file.

`{}` will be replaced with the path of each found `.h` file, and
`--parents` ensures that the file's parent directories are created in the destination directory `libtensorflowlite-2.13.0-linux/include` if they don't exist.