# grep print relative file path when doing a recursive search

Tags: grep, osx, freebsd

I'm trying to find out which version of hibernate the project depends on (this is orthogonal to my question).

We have a parent project with several sub projects, and I know this is defined in one or more `pom.xml`.  The problem is that when it prints a match all it's telling me is the line and that it was found in `pom.xml`, I want to know which sub project `pom.xml`.

How can I get `grep` to print the relative path (absolute would work too but less pretty)? If it's not possible alternative suggestions welcome.

```
$ grep -rI -3 org.hibernate pom.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a combination of find, xargs and grep:

```
 cd top-dir
 find . -print -name 'pom.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l pattern
```

I put in -print0 / -0 option so that special characters in the found directories are protected and properly processed.

The above will list the filename(s) relative to the top-dir matching the patterm.

Comment: this should be more efficient than xargs, but accomplishes the same (including the too many args problem) `find . -name 'pom.xml' -exec grep -3 'org.hibernate' '{}' +`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --with-filename -rI -3 org.hibernate pom.xml
```

From the man page:

```
       -H, --with-filename
          Print  the  file  name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to
          search.
```

Comment: this is the default behavior, it does not give the relative or absolute path, I can't tell the difference between one pom.xml and another with this (or maybe this option is ignored...) . Also this is not in my man page... are you sure this is for a freebsd grep and not gnu grep?

Comment: GNU Grep.  That would be the issue, here.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a `globstar` pattern, i.e. a [*recursive glob*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob), in combination with the `grep` `-H` option to include the file name in the output.

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -H org.hibernate **/pom.xml
```

Unlike the recursive `grep` (`-R`), with this approach, the `-H` option does include the file path in the output.

Hint: you might find it useful to add `shopt -s globstar` to your `.bashrc` to permanently allow recursive globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following command:

```
cat */demo.txt | grep -Rli 'demo'
```

This command will return the path of file.