# Why --exclude of tar doesn't work

Tags: tar

The following simple command yield the following result:

```
$ tar -zcvf clusterops.tgz ansible --exclude='.git' --exclude='.idea' --exclude='**/.ssh' --exclude='*.log' | grep ssh
ansible/.ssh/
ansible/.ssh/ClouderaManagerKey.ppk
ansible/.ssh/ClouderaManagerKey.pem
```

What is going on here? Why the pattern '**/.ssh' fail to do anything?

Comment: At least for GNU tar, AFAIK it only supports "a  glob(3)-style  wildcard  pattern" whereas you appear to be trying to use a "globstar" pattern similar to that provided by some shells - see for example [Recursive glob?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob/49917)

Comment: In effect, you are telling the command to exclude a file called `.ssh` located in any directory within the archive. Instead, use `--exclude='*/.ssh/*'`